How do I search for a phrase in an array and add together the values in a separate column for every row in which that phrase appears in Google Sheets?
I am working on a project to analyse data from a competative pokemon tournament, and I am trying to find the win persentage of every pokemon entered in the tournament.
I have an array with the 6 members of each player's team in rows, and a seperate column that records the number of wins each player had. I'd like to sum together the total number of wins for all the players that featured a specific member on their team.
As an example in the included image, the most common pokemon used is called Flutter Mane, so I want to search through DE:DJ and for every row that contains a Flutter Mane, add their total wins from column E together:
Spreadsheet Screenshot
I tried using this array formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if(DE:DJ=GJ3,E3,0)))
This basically just adds E3 to itself for however many times the value in GJ3 appears in the array. I'm not sure how to add the value in column E in all of the rows were GJ3 appears. I suspect I need to use some type of index function, but I've never used one before and can't find anything online that pertains to the specific thing I'm trying to do
Here's a sheet with a smaller-scale example of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AiirQT_31a_EX7t9mQ3qpUp0YAV_WmoM56Ty9d_AQA/edit?usp=sharing


Here's one approach using sumif():
=map(I2:I14,lambda(Σ,sumif(byrow(C:H,lambda(Λ,xmatch(Σ,Λ)^0)),1,B:B)))


